# removing a word/tag from xml in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, split

I am trying to delete/remove the final tag  from an xml file when I run it and enter new data into the form fields - but it still seems to be staying - and not getting deleted/removed

### XML Dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<models>
<details>
<firstname firstname_id='1'>asdfasdf</firstname>
<middlenames middlenames_id='1'>asdfasdf</middlenames>
<lastname lastname_id='1'>asdfasdf</lastname>
<date date_id='1'>-- -- ---- </date>
<jsexuals jsexuals_id='1'>--</jsexuals>
<height height_id='1'>--</height>
<weight weight_id='1'>--</weight>
<ethnicity ethnicity_id='1'></nationality>
<nationality nationality_id='1'></nationality>
<height height_id='1'></height>
<weight weight_id='1'></weight>
<hair hair_id='1'></hair>
<eyes eyes_id='1'></eyes>
<measurements measurements_id='1'></measurements>
<servicesoffered servicesoffered_id='1'></servicesoffered>
<address address_id='1'></address>
<city city_id='1'></city>
<postalcode postalcode_id='1'></postalcode>
<landlinephone landlinephone_id='1'></landlinephone>
<mobilephone mobilephone_id='1'></mobilephone>
<businessphone businessphone_id='1'></businessphone>
</details>
</models>

<details>
<firstname firstname_id='2'>asdfasd</firstname>
<middlenames middlenames_id='2'>fasdfasdf</middlenames>
<lastname lastname_id='2'>asdfdasf</lastname>
<date date_id='2'>-- -- ---- </date>
<jsexuals jsexuals_id='2'>--</jsexuals>
<height height_id='2'>--</height>
<weight weight_id='2'>--</weight>
<ethnicity ethnicity_id='2'></nationality>
<nationality nationality_id='2'></nationality>
<height height_id='2'></height>
<weight weight_id='2'></weight>
<hair hair_id='2'></hair>
<eyes eyes_id='2'></eyes>
<measurements measurements_id='2'></measurements>
<servicesoffered servicesoffered_id='2'></servicesoffered>
<address address_id='2'></address>
<city city_id='2'></city>
<postalcode postalcode_id='2'></postalcode>
<landlinephone landlinephone_id='2'></landlinephone>
<mobilephone mobilephone_id='2'></mobilephone>
<businessphone businessphone_id='2'></businessphone>
</details>
```

### Code:

```
String fileName = "src/sperm.xml";
String testWord = "</details"; //CHANGE THIS IF YOU WANT
String testWord1 = "</models>";
int wordCntr = 0;
int tLen = testWord.length();
boolean check;
boolean check1;
String l="";
String m  ="";
String l1="";
String root="</models>";

try {
    DOMOutputter output = new DOMOutputter();

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    String strLine1;
    String temp="";
    while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        check = strLine.toLowerCase().contains(testWord.toLowerCase());
        // strLine = strLine.replace("<details>", " ");
        if(check){
            String[] lineWords = strLine.split("\\s+");
            for(String w : lineWords){
                if(w.length() >= tLen){
                    String word = w.substring(0,tLen).trim();
                    if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(testWord)){
                        wordCntr++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
        //check to see whether testWord occurs at least once in the line of text
        //  check1 = strLine1.toLowerCase().contains(testWord);
        strLine1 = strLine1.replace(testWord1, " ");
        check1 = strLine1.toLowerCase().contains(testWord1);
        if(check1){
            String[] lineWords1 = strLine1.split("\\s+");
            for(String v : lineWords1){
                if(v.equalsIgnoreCase(testWord1)){
                    strLine1 = strLine1.replace(testWord1, " "); // I replace</models> in this instant with empty strings
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: anyone home that can help me out?

Comment: It seems that your XML dataset is invalid at this line: `<ethnicity ethnicity_id='1'></nationality>`. Did you validate your XML?

Comment: ya it works but even without that i'm not using xml to remove the last </model> tag before i start inserting more tags until i insert another </model> tag at the fine end again

Comment: i fixed the code...now what?

Comment: If you mean your problem is solved, post the solution as an answer so that future readers are benefitted.

Comment: its not solved...its the errors in the xml that i fixed up...I am still getting problems